# Can we convert unsigned char value from little endian to big endian?

Tags: c++, endianness

If the function htonl() is used to convert little endian to big endian, then it works fine for integer type values, but returning zero for unsigned char or BYTE values.

```
q = (int)htonl((u_long)p);  // integer values
Modulus = (BYTE)htonl((u_long)modulus); // BYTE values
Prime1 = (BYTE)htonl((u_long)prime1); // BYTE values
```

Is it possible to change endianess for BYTE values.

Answer (score 6):

Endianness is defined in terms of bytes; byte reversing one byte wouldn't change the value. You don't need a function, because it's already both little and big endian.